# How to show a Bitmap image from Uri in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap

i want to use Google Static Map API,and Download a Bitmap image of my location and Show it in my app as a image,i wrote this code but my application stopped,what is the problem?

code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.858235,2.294571&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false";
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
         bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageView vi=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.salak);
    vi.setImageBitmap(bmp);


}
```

i just wrote this part of code in the Oncreate() Function and have a ImageViewer in .xml file to show the image, but my program didn't work Corectly,How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You should post your error log, it looks to me that you may be crashing from network on main thread exception, you should probably look into Async task to do your networking on background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JRowan says in his comment, the most likely cause of your problem is that you are trying to do network calls on the main thread,  which is not allowed.

See this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

The easiest way to load an ImageView from a Uri is using Square's Picasso library which can be found here:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

One you have it downloaded and installed, then you can load your ImageView like so:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(yourUrl).into(yourImageView);
```

If run in an activity, you can just use `this`, as the context.